# Is there a method to randomize integers so that visitors can't figure out the sequence of objects

Tags: c#, security, random

I have an id in the url.  So normally it will be an auto number and so it will be 1,2,3,4,5,.....

I don't want visitors to figure out the sequence and so i want to let the number be kinda of random.  So i want 1 to be converted to 174891 and 2 to 817482 and so on.  But i want this to be in a specique range like 1 to 1,000,000.

I figured out i can do this using xoring and shifting  of the bits of the integer.  But i was wondering if this already was implemented in some place.

Thanks

Comment: In what language are you programing?  Most languages have a pseudo random number generator.

Comment: Does it need to be reversible?

Comment: Robert Harvey 9: c#
SLaks: yes it need to be reversable
Will: yes that is not security , i just need to generate reference numbers and  i dont want them to be in sequence so the users can figure out how many items i have.

Comment: Why does it need to be in that range?

Comment: it need to be in that range because of a business decision. but the range is not specifue. it can be 2^20 for example.

Answer (score 6):

You could pass your integer as the seed to a random number generator.  (Just make sure that it would be unique)

You could also generate the SHA-512c hash of the integer and use that instead.

However, the best thing to do here is to use a GUID instead of an integer.

**EDIT**:  If it needs to be reversible, the correct way to do it is to encrypt the number using AES or a different encryption algorithm.  However, this won't result in a number between one and a million.

Comment: Agreed on the guid.  Some sites go a bit further and base64 encode the GUID which results in a smaller and more readable identifier.

Comment: i need to be able to decrypt my integer back so a random number generator wont work.
and i need the number to be in a specific range like 1 to 1000000 so of course the uid wont work.

Comment: @Karim, that's a lot of conditions for just some simple obfuscation.

Comment: Is there a reason you have to use 1-100000, beyond "thats what the system uses"?  Can you modify your code to just use UIDs, or is there a specific reason it must be an integer in that range?

Comment: the range is a business decision and it dont need to be 1 to 100000.
it maybe be a multiple of 2 so 2^20 = 1048576 is perfectly valid.
this will be the reference number. the original number will be a normal sequence.

Answer (score 5):

Don't rely on obscurity -- i.e., non-sequential ids -- for security.  Build your app so that even if someone does guess the next id, it's still secure.

If you do need non-sequential ids, though.  Generate a new id each time randomly.  Store that in your table as a indexed (uniquely) column along with your autogenerated primary key id.  Then all you need to do is a look up on that column to get back the real id.

Comment: well i wanted a method that uses some kind of key and doesnt involve the DB to simplify the system.  
i mean storing the id in the DB is an extra trip to the DB server.

Answer (score 4):

EDIT: In general, I prefer tvanfosson's approach on both scores. However, here's an answer to the question as stated...

These are fairly strange design constraints, to be honest - but they're reasonably easy to deal with:

1. Pick an arbitrary RNG seed which you will use on every execution of your program
2. Create an instance of Random using that seed
3. Create an array of integers 1..1000000
4. Shuffle the array using the Random instance
5. Create a "reverse mapping" array by going through the original array like this:

   ```
      int[] reverseMapping = new int[mapping.Length];
      for (int i = 0; i < mapping.Length; i++)
      {
           reverseMapping[mapping[i]] = i + 1;
      }
   ```

Then you can map both ways. This *does* rely on the algorithm used by `Random` not changing, admittedly... if that's a concern, you could always generate this mapping once and save it somewhere.

Comment: well i wanted something more simple. i was thinking of xor and shifting the bits. and maybe rearanging the bit positions using some kind of table.
that is move bit 1 to 5
and bit 5 to 2 and so on.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for a fairly simple pseudo-random integer sequence, the [linear congruential method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator) is pretty good:

n<sub>i+1</sub> = (*a*×n<sub>i</sub> + *k*) mod *m*

Use prime numbers for *a* and *k*.